# This css only works well on large screens, when the window dimension is modified it gets out of square

Tags: html, css, nav

This css only works well on large screens, for small screens it is out of square.

The code below is from a navigation bar, added a magnifying glass icon and round borders. But when resizing to small screen the magnifying glass does not fit the screen, how can I correct my mistake?

I send the error code and image when the browser window is resized.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 50px;
    outline: 0;  /*not outline field*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(136, 136, 136, 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    width: 300px;
  
}

.topnav .search-container .search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777777;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    padding: 12px 0px 0px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
            }


.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="search-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Search Bar</h2>
  <p>Navigation bar with a search box and a submit button inside of it.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative` to `.seach-container`. The icon will now stay in the search box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  position: relative; /* Add this */
  float: right;
}

.topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 50px;
    outline: 0;  /*not outline field*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(136, 136, 136, 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    width: 300px;
  
}

.topnav .search-container .search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777777;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    padding: 12px 0px 0px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
            }


.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="search-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Search Bar</h2>
  <p>Navigation bar with a search box and a submit button inside of it.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, it worked thanks a lot, is there a way to make it more simplified the css?... I'm noob in design.

Comment: @CharleeS I'm not sure what you mean. What do you want to make more simplified?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put input tag and your button into the div you created for i (font-awesome icon)

the change the style for i (font-awesome icon)

(by the way it's better to put submit button into the form,
or you can use form attribute to link it to your form)

like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 50px;
    outline: 0;  /*not outline field*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(136, 136, 136, 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    width: 300px;
  
}

.topnav .search-container .search-icon i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #777777;
    z-index: 2; 
  }


.topnav .search-container .search-icon button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.topnav .search-container .search-icon button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="search-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Search Bar</h2>
  <p>Navigation bar with a search box and a submit button inside of it.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have given me a good idea. Can the code be more simplified??